# Render spaces in HTML from Javascript strings

Tags: javascript, html, string, whitespace

Here my code:

```
name="Bus/Car";
amount = "21";

return amount + name;
```

This renders:

21Bus/Car

What I want to do is something like this:

```
return amount + "    "  + name;
```

And get:
  21____Bus/Car

(underscores are spaces, stow removes my spaces here to ;-))

I tried to use `&nbsp;`  and to join an array of empty strings but it doesn't works.

I think it should be possible to add html code in a string in between to create a `<p> </p>` with spaces in it but I don't find how to do it.

**EDIT** :
This is my HTML I'm using Polymer here.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.parking]]" as="parking">
    <obj-label theme="neutral-dark">[[_getParking(parking)]]</obj-label>
    <br>
</template>
```

item.parking looks like this:

```
    "parking" : [{"bus" : "2"},
                 {"privat" : "21"}
                ]
```

The javascript part :

```
_getParking : function(parking){
      var name,
          amount = parking[Object.keys(parking)[0]];

      if(Object.keys(parking)[0] == "bus"){
        name="Bus/Car";
      }else{
        name="Privatwagen";
      }

      return amount + name;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you used `&nbsp;` and how you're inserting the content into the page.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```html
<p>21     Bus/Car</p>
```

Nope.

Does... this work?

```html
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap">21     Bus/Car</p>
```

Yup.

Try that.

Alternatives include `&emsp;` (result: 21 Bus/Car) and actually using elements (eg. `<span>`) and styling them to have appropriate margins.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is adding css property to preserve spaces:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this doesn't answers my question but I had to go on and did it now the ugly way:

HTML:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.parking]]" as="parking">
  <div style="width:50px; float:left">
    <obj-label theme="neutral-dark">[[_getParking(parking, "amount")]]</obj-label>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <obj-label theme="neutral-dark">[[_getParking(parking, "name")]]</obj-label>
  </div>
  <br>
</template>
```

JS:

```
  _getParking : function(parking, field){
    var name,
        amount = parking[Object.keys(parking)[0]];
    if(field == "amount"){
      return amount;
    }else{
      if(Object.keys(parking)[0] == "bus"){
        name="Bus/Car";
      }else{
        name="Privatwagen";
      }
        return name;
    }
  }
```